# How to get data from store before render in React-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-thunk

I need to render component by route `"courses/:courseId"`, but I got an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined". It's because `courses` is empty just after render.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams, Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import { pipeDuration } from '../../helpers/pipeDuration';
import { transformDate } from '../../helpers/dateGenerator';
import { selectCourses, selectAuthors } from './selectors';
import { BACK_TO_COURSES } from '../../constants';

import classes from './CourseInfo.module.css';

import { getCourses } from '../../store/courses/thunk';
import { getAuthors } from '../../store/authors/thunk';

const CourseInfo = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAuthors());
    dispatch(getCourses());
  }, []);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { courseId } = useParams();
  const courses = useSelector(selectCourses);
  const authors = useSelector(selectAuthors);
  const course = courses.find((course) => course.id === courseId);

  const createdDate = transformDate(course.creationDate);
  const duration = pipeDuration(course.duration);

  const courseAuthors = course.authors.map((authorId) => {
    return authors.find(({ id }) => id === authorId);
  });

  const courseAuthorsList = courseAuthors.map((author, index, array) => {
    return index + 1 === array.length ? author.name : author.name + ', ';
  });

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <Link to='/courses'>{BACK_TO_COURSES}</Link>
        <h2 className={classes.title}>{course.title}</h2>
        <div className={classes.info}>
          <p className={classes.description}>{course.description}</p>
          <div className={classes.details}>
            <div><strong>ID: </strong>{courseId}</div>
            <div><strong>Duration: </strong>{duration} hours</div>
            <div><strong>Created: </strong>{createdDate}</div>
            <div><strong>Authors: </strong>
              <div className={classes.authorsWrapper}>
                {courseAuthorsList}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CourseInfo;
```

How can I initialize `courses` const before render?

Comment: Create initial state for courses in redux store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that the `CourseInfo` component isn't being very defensive about protecting itself against potentially undefined values. Assuming the selected `courses` state is an array you should keep in mind that [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#return_value) returns `undefined` when no array element is matched back the predicate callback function.

> ### Return value
>
> The first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing
> function. Otherwise, `undefined` is returned.

The `useEffect` hook runs after the component is rendered to the DOM during the "commit phase".

Your current code:

```
const CourseInfo = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAuthors());
    dispatch(getCourses());
  }, []);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { courseId } = useParams();
  const courses = useSelector(selectCourses);
  const authors = useSelector(selectAuthors);

  const course = courses.find((course) => course.id === courseId); // <-- potentially undefined

  const createdDate = transformDate(course.creationDate); // <-- potential undefined access
  const duration = pipeDuration(course.duration); // <-- potential undefined access

  const courseAuthors = course.authors.map((authorId) => { // <-- potential undefined access
    return authors.find(({ id }) => id === authorId);
  });

  const courseAuthorsList = courseAuthors.map((author, index, array) => {
    return index + 1 === array.length ? author.name : author.name + ', ';
  });

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <Link to='/courses'>{BACK_TO_COURSES}</Link>
        <h2 className={classes.title}>
          {course.title} // <-- potential undefined access
        </h2>
        <div className={classes.info}>
          <p className={classes.description}>
            {course.description} // <-- potential undefined access
          </p>
          <div className={classes.details}>
            <div><strong>ID: </strong>{courseId}</div>
            <div><strong>Duration: </strong>{duration} hours</div>
            <div><strong>Created: </strong>{createdDate}</div>
            <div><strong>Authors: </strong>
              <div className={classes.authorsWrapper}>
                {courseAuthorsList}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

## Solution

A simple solution would be to check for a defined `courses` state value prior to attempting to access into the object.

```
const CourseInfo = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAuthors());
    dispatch(getCourses());
  }, []);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { courseId } = useParams();
  const courses = useSelector(selectCourses);
  const authors = useSelector(selectAuthors);

  const course = courses.find((course) => course.id === courseId);

   // Check for falsey course value
  if (!course) {
    return <div>No courses found.</div>;
  }

  const createdDate = transformDate(course.creationDate);
  const duration = pipeDuration(course.duration);

  // Guard against undefined course.authors and author arrays
  const courseAuthors = (course.authors || [])
    // Map found author objects
    .map((authorId) => (authors || []).find(({ id }) => id === authorId))
    // Filter any undefined "holes" for unknown authors
    .filter(Boolean)
    // Map to author's name property
    .map((author) => author.name)
    // Join into comma-separated list string
    .join(", ");

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <Link to='/courses'>{BACK_TO_COURSES}</Link>
        <h2 className={classes.title}>
          {course.title}
        </h2>
        <div className={classes.info}>
          <p className={classes.description}>
            {course.description}
          </p>
          <div className={classes.details}>
            <div><strong>ID: </strong>{courseId}</div>
            <div><strong>Duration: </strong>{duration} hours</div>
            <div><strong>Created: </strong>{createdDate}</div>
            <div><strong>Authors: </strong>
              <div className={classes.authorsWrapper}>
                {courseAuthors}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```